# How to fetch to-many relationships in Core data in IOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have been trying to fetch relationship values of to-many relationship in core data.
I have to two entity Person and Address. Person can have multiple address and it has two attributes Name & age. While address just has one attribute City.

Here is how I'm trying to set the values

```
let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)!.managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
let addEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Address", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

let address = NSManagedObject(entity: addEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
person.setValue(age, forKey: "age")
address.setValue(city, forKey: "city")

person.setValue(NSSet(object: address), forKey: "addresses")

do {
    try person.managedObjectContext?.save()
    people.append(person)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save \(error)")
}
```

This is how my core data properties are set

```
extension Person {

   @NSManaged var age: NSNumber?
   @NSManaged var name: String?
   @NSManaged var addresses: Address?

}

extension Address {

   @NSManaged var city: String?
   @NSManaged var persons: Person?

}
```

Then to fetch the data in table view I'm trying to do something like this

```
let person = people[indexPath.row]
let address = person.mutableSetValueForKey("addresses")
print(address.allObjects.first as! Address)
```

Value of the print is something like this

```
<Address: 0x7f9481f1e290> (entity: Address; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://7A4230B9-0EF0-44D5-BBDD-D8E9A3E38F59/Address/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is much simpler to create the inverse relationships in your model as well, so an inverse from address back to person.  Then simply set `address.person=person`  Core Data will then take care of the forward relationship for you

Comment: @Paulw11 I have already set the inverse relationship in data model. My question is how to retrieve string from NSSet?

Comment: `let someAddress = address.allObjects.first` - you already have this code.  Then simply something like `print(someAddress.city)`

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 its works
I guess we need to do something like this:
let addressRln = person.valueForKey("addresses")
let  address = addressRln?.allObjects.first as! Address
print(address.city)

Answer (score 0):

Check it is relationship (not attribute). And is to-many. Like this:
[image]
After that, it will like this:

```
extension Album {

    @NSManaged var createDate: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var isDefault: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var order: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var picture: NSData?
    @NSManaged var notes: NSOrderedSet? // Attention: NSOrderedSet

}
```

Comment: I have regenerated the core data model and this is what is set now @NSManaged var addresses: NSSet?

Comment: @AshutoshJha And then set addresses and save,just like common attributes.

Comment: @AshutoshJha As you saved addresses, access them by `person.addresses`

Answer (score 0):

The model you are showing is not what you state it to be.  Your model shows a mis-named 1:1 relationship.  Based on your code, you should bet getting a crash.

```
@NSManaged var addresses: Address?  // is not a 1:N
```

I recommend you review your data model and regenerate your code.